# Azure Cosmos DB Emulator : Unable to connect to MongoDb via MongoChef

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, studio3t

After following the instructions from the following official reference ["Use the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator for local development and testing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator), we attempted to connect to MongoDb using MongoChef using the connection string pasted below:

```
mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true
```

But when we test the connection through MongoChef we get the error pasted below:

**Connection failed.
SERVER [localhost:10255] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ Socket error: Connection refused: connect
Details:
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]**

If we check the ports currently in use on our system, we do not see 10255 being used at all.

Could someone please help us understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string is correct. Studio 3T has a very nasty bug - when you use From URI function while creating new connection it cuts the "+" characters that are present in the key, that's why you need to copy the key manually to the corresponding field in connection properties. 
Also, make sure the Emulator is actually launched (tray area icon should be present).